# Get anchor part of URL in controller in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, anchor

Is there a way to get the anchor part of a URL in a controller?

Example: if I type http://www.foo.com/bar#anchor123 can I get the string anchor123 in my controller?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can't do that in Rails, because the anchor is not sent to the server. See [mikeduncan.com/?s=named+anchors](https://web.archive.org/web/20131215235427/http://www.mikeduncan.com/?s=named+anchors)

Comment: The post is dead again.

Answer (score 34):

No sorry, it's not possible to retrieve the #anchor from the server-side (in any language).

This is a client-side flag to tell the browser to move to a specific position in the page.

But you can use some Javascript in the body to check for an anchor and send it back to the server using an Ajax-call...

```
var anchor_value;
var stripped_url = document.location.toString().split("#");
if (stripped_url.length > 1)
  anchor_value = stripped_url[1];
```

Comment: Might be nicer to use `window.location.hash` to get the value of the anchor rather than `split`ting..? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hash