# extracting url component in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to build a facebook based application, I am not using any pre-existing facebook gems etc, therefore have to build it afresh.

After authentication, I receive the access_token back from facebook as part of the callback url. It comes along as `https://server/path#access_token=<token from facebook>`

I need  to extract access_token for authenticating my further requests.  I am not able to get the # onwards parts of the url in the reqeust object...

I have already tried the request object and params hash... nothing provides me the "complete" url...

help...

Comment: you can't do on server side. you can use javascript `var url = window.location.href`

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108082/get-anchor-part-of-url-in-controller-in-ruby-on-rails