# Tracking Users coming from a certain source

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, get, tracking

I'm giving promotions to users who sends us other visitors. This is done on the **client side**.

I can do this using dynamic GET parameters, e.g. `http://www.mysite.com?app_source=user_id` or I can do this using the hash, e.g. `http://www.mysite.com#app_source,user_id`.

Are there any pros and cons for any of these methods?

Comment: How is the tracking accomplished if it's done on the client side?

Comment: This is a third party app. We parse the `document.location` object and POST to our servers, just like Google Analytics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Query String

- Google Analytics, server logs, et al will have a record of the URL, which may be beneficial for later analysis.
- Multiple URLs make caching harder and have a slight chance of confusing the Google

#### Hash

- Analytics and server logs will not see/pay attention to hash params

The more *semantic* way of handling this is probably through a query string parameter, but it's not very strong. If none of the above-listed points is relevant, I would probably just stick with query strings because it is more common.

If you mean that you are building a service that other people integrate, and you don't want them to have to pass information back to their application (via query string), then using hash params seems like a solid option.

Answer (score 8):

The standard way to do this for a GET request would be to simply use a query string.

```
http://www.mysite.com?app_source=user_id
```

---

If you use a URL anchor such as

```
http://www.mysite.com#app_source,user_id
```

The anchor portion (`#app_source,user_id`) **is not sent to the server**

For example, see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774136/retrieving-anchor-link-in-url-for-asp-net).

Here's another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108082/get-anchor-part-of-url-in-controller-in-ruby-on-rails)

The anchor is merely a client-side flag to tell the browser where to navigate on the page.

---

To address your redirect concerns, you can process the query string before redirecting, add/remove and key/value pairs you want, and then redirect.

PHP gives you direct access to the query string with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Rails uses `request.uri` which you can [parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316656/how-to-get-query-string-from-passed-url-in-ruby-on-rails)

Also, when you see fanciful things like `facebook.com/#stuff`, the anchor portion is handled with client-side javascript.  So you **can** do this, but you'll be writing ajax code that is sending normal GET requests like the one recommended at the top of this answer.

Why add complexity?  Do you just like the look of the `#` better than the `?` ?

Comment: This is a third party script. Redirections - and parsing dynamic arguments before redirection - are not possible. Other third party scripts, like AddThis, use the hash and not dynamic parameters.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `?` approach. Why? Because that's how you should pass arbitrary data across pages.

`#` is specifically used for page anchors.

Semantics and best practices aside, there is also a practical reason for this. Think about what happens when a user sends a visitor to an anchor on a page. You would not be able to use the hash approach (at least not in a simple way).

So I would follow the approach outlined [here](http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/06/10/reading-get-variables-with-javascript/):

```
function $_GET(q,s) {
    s = s ? s : window.location.search;
    var re = new RegExp('&'+q+'(?:=([^&]*))?(?=&|$)','i');
    return (s=s.replace(/^?/,'&').match(re)) ? (typeof s[1] == 'undefined' ? '' : decodeURIComponent(s[1])) : undefined;
}

var app_source = $_GET('app_source');
```

Then you can have URLs like this: `http://www.mysite.com?app_source=user_id#anchor`

Answer (score 3):

W3C says [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html):

> Naturally, it is not possible to ensure that the server does not
>   generate  side-effects as a result of performing a GET request; in
>   fact, some dynamic  resources consider that a feature. The important
>   distinction here is that the user  did not request the side-effects,
>   so therefore cannot be held accountable for them.

Answer (score 3):

Use HASH.

Why?

Because you develop 3rd party plugin, and don't know if any of the arguments are NOT user by site developers. When you override one of used get parameters, you can destroy some important information passed to the server by native app devs.
Also you don't want to make app holder having duplicated pages like: http://somepage.com/ and http://somepage.com/?app_source=user_id will be duplicates and as many users will refer that page, you will create many of them.

Hash is the most safe option and can be used on every page.

Answer (score 2):

Hash is the way to go.

There are only 2 choices, one is GET Parameter and 2nd is #.

**? GET PARAMETER**

The get parameter can be indexed by search engine and two URLs `http://www.yoursite.com/` and `http://www.yoursite.com/?app_id=123` can be 2 seperate pages

On one of my sites I have used this and I get emails from google stating 
`While crawling your site, we have noticed an increase in the number of transient soft 404 errors around 2012-06-30 22:00 UTC (London, Dublin, Edinburgh). Your site may have experienced outages. These issues may have been resolved. Here are some sample pages that resulted in soft 404 errors:`

The links they mentioned are working properly without any issue, but still I am started to get these errors.

**# HASH**

Hashes are better as they dont change the behavior of any SEO thing (many ppl will say that it does have impact but i dont think so)

At the end you just need to get the `app_source` and to pass it to your server using Javascript. So you can as what you like. If I were you, i would surly use HASH

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your methods are good. 
The ultimate way to do this is to use URL Segments:

If you want to differentiate by App and UserId:

```
http://www.mysite.com/appName/UserID/
```

Or only by UserId:

```
http://www.mysite.com/UserID/
```

But I personally would go by both AppName and UserName:

```
http://www.mysite.com/appName/UserName/
```

Comment: Totally wrong - he's developing 3rd party javascript plugin, and don't want to mess up app URL's. You don't even know if this app wont throw 404 error using you approach.

Comment: @MaciejPyszyński Not sure what you mean by "mess up", also 404 is thrown on the server and has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: Yes. do if base url is http://somepage.com/page-ulrname and only this is url format is supported by App, and this guy is developing 3rd party plugin, so he cannot add parameters to URL. Other case is when app use parameter appName, so he may provide wrong input. Another one is hash can be used on every page, without any flaws (if application don't use hash to restore some state)

Comment: Well, now you have completely lost me because I don't understand your English. Try to formulate your sentences in more clear manner.

Comment: Sorry was in hurry.  
If base url is http://somepage.com/[page-ulrname] and this is only supported format. You will get 404 error. Moreover this guy is developing 3rd party plugin, so he cannot add parameters to URL or enforce dev team to do so. We run in another problem when app use parameter "appName", so it can provide wrong input (by URL). Also hash can be used on every page, without any flaws (if application don't use hash to restore some state)

Comment: If OP doesn't have control over the URL, then my answer is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Based on some modern web applications today that have promoted the "#" sign is very useful to support SPA (Single Page Application) like Twitter. Please just use the "?" sign.

Comment: If the website will redirect to another page I will lose the dynamic parameters but I won't lose the hash information. See http://fb.com/#stuff as an example

Comment: @CamelCamelCamel, I addressed your redirect concern in my answer.

Comment: That's why I have suggested you to use the ? GET parameter sign and not the # HASH. Good luck.

Comment: Well, if you really think about it. No matter if you are going to use the ? GET PARAMETER or the # HASH, somewhere you'll make an ajax request to actually deal with sessions and updating your database, thus updating your app state. The ? GET PARAMETER is just more natural for me and maybe for most developers.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to use a GET parameter with a userID to verify if it's been referred by someone.

```
http://www.mysite.com/?ref=1128721
```

Then if you want to know more about the referral, you can also check from which url the user actually clicked your link by using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` (if you use php). This way, you can ensure that your link wasn't in a junk place or "auto-visited".