# rails Do not call before_filter for a specific URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, controllers

I am defining a before_filter :authorize_special_user, which checks if the special condition exists or not. If yes, then it is okay, otherwise I redirect to a URL like "/users/special#account". So how do I specify the before_filter to NOT be called on the URL "/users/special#account"? Normally it is done by

```
before_filter :authorize_special_users :except => [ :users ]
```

But it will not work here. I tried

```
before_filter :authorize_special_users :except => [ "/users/special#account" ]
```

but it does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution would be to wrap the code inside the before filter in a conditional:

```
def authorize_special_users
    unless request.path == "/users/special"
        ...
    end
end
```

Comment: hmm...I tried this, but turns out that request.path is only emitting "/users/special" and omitting the "#account" path. Any ideas, why?

Comment: It doesn't seem that it is possible to send the anchor ("#account") to the server. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108082/get-anchor-part-of-url-in-controller-in-ruby-on-rails#4108270