# Ruby on Rails - passing parameters in link_to with if conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to pass a parameter (for example the param is called company=heise) on a link to, but only if the param really is present.

Lets say:

I visit `somesite.com` and click a link that would redirect me to  `mysite.com/?company=heise`
On `mysite` i have a few link_to's and I want them to pass the parameter `company=heise` when it's present and since it is present now because I entered the site via `mysite.com/?company=heise` it should do the following:

```
<%= link_to "This is a link", this_link_path, class: tl(this_link_path) %>
```

should redirect me to `mysite.com/this_link/?company=heise`

- If company=heise is set I want to display them in the URL and I furthermore want to not display it when it's not set.

Hope I made my question clear enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditionally pass a hash, containing additional params for `this_link_path` url helper.

```
<%= link_to "This is a link", this_link_path( ({company: params[:company] } if params[:company]) ), class: tl(this_link_path) %>
```

To be more concise you can [compact](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/compact) the hash.

```
<%= link_to "This is a link", this_link_path({company: params[:company]}.compact), class: tl(this_link_path) %>
```

If you know that you'll need it more often, wrap `this_link_path` call in a custom helper. Hash can contain additional params, including ones with fixed values.

```
def this_link_with_additional_params_path
  this_link_path({company: params[:company], name: 'test'}.compact) 
end
```

Then in view you can use:

```
<%= link_to "This is a link", this_link_with_additional_params_path, class: tl(this_link_path) %>
```

Comment: Yes, i do know that I need to use this more often. Is there any way to provide another param that is always set? For example: I always want have a param called name=test set, and the company one only if the condition is true.

Comment: @benl96 Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you really much! That worked just fine. Only problem left now is while using anchors.
mysite.com/test/?company=heise is my entry URL - now I want to go to a specific anchor but the URL looks like this after clicking on the anchor link mysite.com/test.company=heise#anchor instead of mysite.com/test/?company=heise#anchor. Do you know how to get the correct URL for anchors as well?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108082/get-anchor-part-of-url-in-controller-in-ruby-on-rails unfortunately, you can't read them on Rails side.

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to create a helper method to manage the params that you want to send to this link conditionally.

```
# some_helper.rb
def carried_over_params(params = {})
  interesting_keys = %i(company)
  params.slice(*interesting_keys).compact
end
```

Afterwards, you should use this in the view

```
<%= link_to "This is a link", this_link_path(carried_over_params(params).merge(test: 'value')), class: tl(this_link_path) %>
```

Comment: Seems like this works!
Could I provide the link_to a extra param that is always set?
For example I want another param on this link to with the name name and the value test
--- This resolves in syntax error obviously ---
<%= link_to "This is a link", this_link_path(name: 'test' carried_over_params(params)), class: tl(this_link_path) %>

Comment: updated the answer to address what you are asking here. Please add it to your original question.