# How to get the full URL including hash in Rails/Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails with a SPA (React).
When trying to get the full path, I cannot seem to be able to get the entire path after the domain. It always truncates everything after the hash:

```
url: http://localhost:3000/r?locale=en#/site-personalization
```

`request.fullpath` returns:

```
/r?locale=en
```

`request.path` returns:

```
/r
```

What method can I use to get everything including the `#/site-personalization` portion of the URL?

I'm hoping that "[Get anchor part of URL in controller in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108082/get-anchor-part-of-url-in-controller-in-ruby-on-rails)" is not the same problem as what I'm facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anchors are not being sent to the server so that's why you cannot get them.

Comment: I was afraid of that... any suggestions to accomplish what I want?
Any suggestions on how to accomplish what I want without using React/Cookies?

Comment: Would URL encoding the # to %23 work for you?  So the URL would be http://localhost:3000/r?locale=en%23/site-personalization